# How to generate database table models with Gii in Yii?

Tags: php, class, yii, gii

**Problem:**

I used [gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii#using-gii) to generate database table models. So If I have any change in users table structure, I used gii and all my relations and other methods are removed from class. So I need to make backup of class and regenerate class and bring back other methods and relations.

**Possible Solution:**

I changed my class into two classes like this for a table 'users':

```
class Users extends UsersMapper {

    public function tableName() {
        return 'users';
    }

    public function rules() {
       .....
    }

    public function relations() {
       .....
    } 
}


class UsersMapper extends CActiveRecord {

    public function getAllUsers() {
       ......
    }

    public function getBlockedUsers() {
       ......
    }   
}
```

**Question:**

Above method is working for me and I am using only `Users` class everywhere in my code. Is it valid method or there is any problem with this logic. Is there any other method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [Giix](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/giix) extension will create a `models/Users` class and a `models/_base/BaseUsers` class for your case. The Users class extends the BaseUsers class. Thus only the BaseUsers class needs to be regenerated on changing the database. It also comes with a couple of extra methods that I use quite a lot.